# Adicionar @onchange no EditorFor usando Razor

Tags: c#, razor

Olá, estou tentando adicionar o @onchange no meu `EditorFor`, pois, vou ter que ir adicionando esse campo dinamicamente

**LINHA ATUAL**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CEP, new { @class = "classe" }, new { @onchange = "myfunction(id)" } })
```

ai no meu caso, iria ter outra linha dessa, passando o id desse campo na funcao

está com erro. como deveria ficar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CEP, new { @class = "classe", onchange = "myfunction(id)" })
```

Comment: Obrigado @Cigano :)

Answer (score 2):

Saindo dessa parte de adicionar diretamente no `HtmlHelper` você pode fazer com `jQuery`. Ficaria assim:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CEP, new { @class = "classe", id=ViewBag.Id })

<script>
      $('.classe').change(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(id);
        });
</script>
```